# can't filter current month data php

Tags: php

I want to filter current month data but facing a problem:

### To get current month in English like 'MAR':

```
$months = array(01 => "JAN", 02 => "FEB", 03 => "MAR", 04 => "APR", 05 => "MAY", 06 => "JUN", 07 => "JUL", 08 => "AUG", 09 => "SEP", 10 => "OCT", 11 => "NOV", 12 => "DEC");
                                        $date = getdate();
                                        $month = $date['mon'];
                                        $Month_Name = $months[$month];
                                        echo $Month_Name;
```

### php query:

```
$query = oci_parse($con, "SELECT FIR.*, ACCUSED.* FROM FIR INNER JOIN ACCUSED ON FIR.FIR_NO = ACCUSED.FIR_NO WHERE FIR_DATE = '$Month_Name' ORDER BY FIR_DATE DESC");
```

Now the problem is that if i do `FIR_DATE = '04-$Month_Name-14'` this works beacuse my date format is like `08-MAR-14` but this will not allow me to get month data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood well, but I think this is what you want.

```
$query = oci_parse($con, "SELECT FIR.*, ACCUSED.* FROM FIR INNER JOIN ACCUSED 
ON FIR.FIR_NO = ACCUSED.FIR_NO WHERE 
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FIR_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'MON')= '$Month_Name' 
ORDER BY FIR_DATE DESC");
```

Comment: getting no error but no result either. i want something like this

Comment: hmm if you see this here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f9fb/6 you'll see that `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FIR_DATE, 'DD-MONTH-YYYY'), 'MON')` returns 3 letters month name, echo the query, let's see how it looks.

Comment: Udated my answer, try it like this

Comment: @user3266957 can you echo the query string let's see it `echo "SELECT FIR.*, ACCUSED.* FROM FIR INNER JOIN ACCUSED 
ON FIR.FIR_NO = ACCUSED.FIR_NO WHERE 
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FIR_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'MON')= '$Month_Name' 
ORDER BY FIR_DATE DESC"`

Comment: SELECT FIR.*, ACCUSED.* FROM FIR INNER JOIN ACCUSED ON FIR.FIR_NO = ACCUSED.FIR_NO WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FIR_DATE, 'D-M-Y'), 'MON')= 'MAR' ORDER BY FIR_DATE DESC

Comment: this `(FIR_DATE, 'D-M-Y'),` should be: `(FIR_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),`

Comment: same nothing showing up. i will try and will let u know

Comment: @user3266957 great! what was the issue?

Comment: i was using echo date('M'); to get the current month. when i used my method which i mentioned above it started to work. these are same or different Mar or MAR?

Comment: @user3266957 Different, if you want to use upper case keep this: `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FIR_DATE, 'D-M-Y'), 'MON')` if you want to use first letter upper then the rest lower: use this: `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FIR_DATE, 'D-M-Y'), 'Mon')` here's an explanation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f9fb/14

Answer (score 0):

To get the current month you don't need this.

```
echo date('M');
```

will display it in the format you are looking for.
More formats are available, you will find them on [date() documentation page](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php).